# Upload and set default file in managed_file field on module install

Tags: 8, forms, configuration

I have managed_file in my module configuration form and one text field, so I want to set default values for these fields on module install.

At the moment I have this in `config/install/my_module.settings.yml`:

```
title: 'Hello!'
langcode: en
```

and this in `config/schema/my_module.schema.yml`:

```
my_module.settings:
  type: config_object
  mapping:
    title:
      type: string
      label: 'Title'
    langcode:
      type: string
      label: 'Language code'
```

Now, how I can upload some PNG image file on module install and how to define it in `my_module.schema.yml` and `my_module.settings.yml` in order to set it as default?

---

**Update**

If I want to leave this field empty is this right way to define it in config?

`config/install/my_module.settings.yml`

```
title: 'Hello!'
image: NULL
langcode: en
```

`config/schema/my_module.schema.yml`

```
my_module.settings:
  type: config_object
  mapping:
    title:
      type: string
      label: 'Title'
    image:
      type: integer
      label: 'Image'
    langcode:
      type: string
      label: 'Language code'
```

This doesn't work, the problem is to define managed_file in schema file, how to do that?

Comment: You need a form to upload a file, so perhaps set a message in `hook_install` inviting users to visit an admin form where they can do so. Or, include the file with your module, then use the API to save it as a managed file without an upload. It probably can't go in the settings.yml as you won't know the file ID ahead of time

Comment: hey @Clive thanks for the answer...I updated my question, can you take a look and confirm me that I'm on the right way?